# firebase web notification - How to use document or window.document in firebase-messaging-sw.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

I have Implemented firebase web notification in my site. I am facing issue in using window.document or document object in service worker firebase-messaging-sw.js.

```
messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  // Handle notification when site is in background

  // // Blink title
  var isOldTitle = true;
  var oldTitle = document.title;
  var newTitle =  "(1) New Work Order";
  var interval = null;
  interval = setInterval(function(){
      document.title = isOldTitle ? oldTitle : newTitle;
      isOldTitle = !isOldTitle;
  }, 700);

  // send web browser notification
  var payloadData = JSON.parse(payload.data.notification);
  var notificationOptions = {
    body: payloadData.body,
    icon: payloadData.icon,
    click_action: payloadData.click_action
  };
  return self.registration.showNotification(payloadData.title,notificationOptions);

});
```

Can anyone suggest me a way to use document object in firebase-messaging-sw.js.

Basically I want achieve is on the notification received I want to change the title of my web site.

Answer (score 2):

Window or document object will not be available inside service worker file. Only way is to communicate to your html or js files. Communication can be send via postmessage api in serviceworker.

```
self.clients.matchAll().then(clients => {
    clients.forEach(client => {
      client.postmessage(/*data*/);
    });
  });
```

In your main document, listen for the messages from service worker using:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage = (event) => {
  console.log('message from sw');
  /*Here change the document title*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Indragith's answer helped me a lot but I had to enable the option includeUncontrolled when I got all client list.

This code worked on my project:

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(payload => {
    console.log(payload)
    self.clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true}).then(clients => {
        clients.forEach(client => {
            client.postMessage('YOUR_MESSAGE')
        })
    })
});
```

Complete answer and explanation here: [Updating Web App User Interface when application is in background FCM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165969/updating-web-app-user-interface-when-application-is-in-background-fcm)